# CakePHP - Using JSON as a datasource

Tags: json, cakephp, datasource

I'm new here so apologies in advance if I break any rules. I'm trying to use a json datasource in cakephp. I've had little progress since viewing the twitter example in the cake documentation. I can get the /model/ listing to work, but associations do not populate and I'm generally flying blind. I was wondering if anyone had any good resources they could direct me to, as the online references that I can find seem few and far between.

Thanks.

Update: My reference material was: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html

Embarrassing but it's just occurred to me that this code cares little about associations. It solves the problem of "How do I present data from twitter as a model in a cakephp application?" without concerning itself with assocations between other related models. Not quite the "automagic" it presented itself as, but having taken a deeper look it's safe to say that there shouldn't be any to begin with.

If I figure it out I'll post code here. I'm going to piggy-back off the dbosource file and how it's read function handles associations.

Comment: Associations are basically joins between database tables, if you use something like json or mongodb you wont able to use them except you write your own code to somehow build them.

Comment: Got it. So basically I was trying to use the json data source to interface a mssql database with the mysql one that I was making, and I was trying to associate the data on the cake end between the two datasources. No dice. Instead I'm using the model's `afterFind` method to add an index to the returned model array, using the primary key as a reference for a json lookup that will then populate my model with whatever mssql-datasource-d info I need.